# AWS Lambda test event ->Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to get the another AWS accout's DynamoDB Data,so I used the '@aws-sdk/client-sts' library to assume a role is send with an AssumeRoleCommand.But after the test,I got the error of Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send').This is the code:
Any help would be appreciated.

```
import { DynamoDBClient, ScanCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

import { fromCognitoIdentity } from "@aws-sdk/credential-provider-cognito-identity";

import { STS, AssumeRoleCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sts";

export const handler = async (event, context) => {

  try {

    const roleBArn = 'arn:aws:iam::<>:role/aws-new';

    const RoleCommand = new AssumeRoleCommand({

      RoleArn: roleBArn,

      RoleSessionName: 'AssumeRoleSession'

    });

    const sts = new STS();

    const assumeRoleResponse = await sts.send(RoleCommand);

    const credentials = assumeRoleResponse.Credentials;

    const dynamodb = new DynamoDBClient({

      region: 'us-west-2',

      credentials: fromCognitoIdentity({

        accessKeyId: credentials.AccessKeyId,

        secretAccessKey: credentials.SecretAccessKey,

        sessionToken: credentials.SessionToken

      })

    });

    const params = {

      TableName: 'MYNEWDB',

      // Add other DynamoDB parameters as needed

    };

    const dynamoDBResponse = await dynamodb.send(new ScanCommand(params));

    console.log('Data from DynamoDB:', dynamoDBResponse);

    return {

      statusCode: 200,

      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Data from DynamoDB', data: dynamoDBResponse })

    };

  } catch (error) {

    console.error('Error:', error);

    return {

      statusCode: 500,

      body: JSON.stringify({ error: 'Internal Server Error' })

    };

  }

};
```

I want to get the Data from DynamoDB by another AWS account.
I used this way and it's worked by index.js,but I want to use the index.mjs and success.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

  try {

    // Role B ARN

    const roleBArn = 'arn:aws:iam::647813465547:role/aws-new';

    // Assume Role B

    const sts = new AWS.STS();

    const assumeRoleResponse = await sts.assumeRole({

      RoleArn: roleBArn,

      RoleSessionName: 'AssumeRoleSession'

    }).promise();

    // Extract temporary credentials

    const credentials = assumeRoleResponse.Credentials;

    // Configure DynamoDB with the assumed role credentials

    const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({

      region: 'us-west-2',

      accessKeyId: credentials.AccessKeyId,

      secretAccessKey: credentials.SecretAccessKey,

      sessionToken: credentials.SessionToken

    });

    // Now you can interact with DynamoDB using the assumed role credentials

    const params = {

      TableName: 'MYNEWDB',

      // Add other DynamoDB parameters as needed

    };

    const dynamoDBResponse = await dynamodb.scan(params).promise();

    // Process DynamoDB data or perform other operations

    console.log('Data from DynamoDB:', dynamoDBResponse);

    return {

      statusCode: 200,

      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Data from DynamoDB', data: dynamoDBResponse })

    };

  } catch (error) {

    console.error('Error:', error);

    return {

      statusCode: 500,

      body: JSON.stringify({ error: 'Internal Server Error' })

    };

  }

};
```

Comment: What lambda runtime are you using and can you share your package.json file contents here?

Comment: The runtime is Node.js 18.x,and there is no package.json file,because I used the package by [import ... from "@aws-sdk"]

Answer (score 0):

You may need STSClient here, not 'STS'. Take a look at [this example in the AWS SDK Code Examples Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/iam_example_iam_Scenario_CreateUserAssumeRole_section.html). Here is the relevant code for assuming a role:

```
    import { AssumeRoleCommand, STSClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-sts";
...
  // Assume the role.
  const stsClient = new STSClient({
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: SecretAccessKey,
    },
  });

  // Retry the assume role operation until it succeeds.
  const { Credentials } = await retry(
    { intervalInMs: 2000, maxRetries: 60 },
    () =>
      stsClient.send(
        new AssumeRoleCommand({
          RoleArn: Role.Arn,
          RoleSessionName: `iamBasicScenarioSession-${Math.floor(
            Math.random() * 1000000,
          )}`,
          DurationSeconds: 900,
        }),
      ),
  );
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.But I tried it,but it doesn't work,the error is still there.I'll try it in other ways.

Comment: Could you post the updated code?